# Is there a way to get the popular hours with the api?

Tags: google-places-api

Is there a way to get the popular hours for a particular place using the api?
I found that it returs the open hours, but there Is nothing about popular hours.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'd be interested in this feature request: [Issue 8581: Popular Times](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8581).